# Evaluating training samples for supervised image classification in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: software-recommendations, classification, arcgis-pro, tools, documentation

Its my first time using ArcGIS Pro and I have started doing a supervised classification.

In most software you have some tools such as histograms, scatterplots and/or statistics to evaluate training samples but I couldn't find any of these tools in the ArcGIS Pro image classification options.

Are they hidden in another menu or did they really didn't include these tools?

I could not find any information regarding this in the help documentation, tutorials or forums.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ArcGIS Pro is still in the process of increasing it's toolset, that's an optimistic outlook, others have had similar questions in other forums, [Where is the classification histogram?](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/167096) and [ArcGIS Pro - histograms within graduated colour symbology](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/160970).

Currently, to access Histogram and Statistics information your best option is to you the [Histogram and Statistics Function](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/imagery/statistics-and-histogram-function.htm#GUID-38B71978-CF75-4DDE-B59A-5659CB25DEFD)

> The Statistics and Histogram function is used to define the statistics and histogram of a raster. You can insert this function at the end of the processing template to describe the statistics and histogram of the processing. This may be needed to control the default display of the processing result, especially when defining a processing template that contains many functions.

You could also make a scatter plot using this approach from [Esri's documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/charts/scatter-plot.htm)

> Use scatter plots to visualize the relationship between two numeric variables, where one variable is displayed on the x-axis, and the other variable is displayed on the y-axis. For each record, a point is plotted where the two variables intersect in the chart. When the resulting points form a nonrandom structure, a relationship exists between the two variables.

[image]

Also, in general you can see which tool are not available for [ArcGIS Pro](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/appendices/unavailable-tools.htm)